# R - Is there a way to dowlnoad the closing prices for DAX companies?

Tags: r, return, quantmod, ticker

I have to download the daily returns for all companies from [2009-06-30] to [2019-06-30]. At first this sounds very simple. But the challenge is to exchange the companies dynamically. For example if a company does not belong to the DAX index anymore I have to replace it with the "new" company.

First of all I thought the package `quantmod` could be helpfull. In the first step I selected all companies which belong to the DAX index throughout.

```
stocks=new.env()
startDate=as.Date("2008-06-30")
endDate=as.Date("2019-06-30")
tickers=c("ADS.DE","ALV.DE","BAS.DE","BMW.DE","BAYN.DE","BEI.DE","DAI.DE","DBK.DE","DB1.DE","DPW.DE","DTE.DE","EOAN.DE","FME.DE","FRE.DE","HEN3.DE","LIN.DE","LHA.DE","MRK.DE","MUV2.DE","RWE.DE","SAP.DE","SIE.DE","TKA.DE","VOW3.DE")        
my.data=lapply(tickers, function(x) try(na.omit(getSymbols(x,src="yahoo",env=stocks,from=startDate,to=endDate,auto.assign = FALSE))))
names(my.data)=tickers
```

I have used function `na.omit` because EOAN.DE, FRE.DE and LIN.DE contain missing values. Especially for FRE.DE are no values on yahoo.finance available. This really complicates my further analysis because my elements have not the same length.

The second problem is that I have no idea how to exchange the companies dynamically. I could download the prices for each company seperatly with different time frames.

I would really appreciate it if someone knows a betther approach in R.

Comment: FYI, I removed the DAX tag as that's a programming language and put R instead.

Comment: One approach is store for each day what the constituents in the index are. For most days, they will be the same as the previous day, but on some days they will change.  You need to get the index weights/constituents on a daily basis from some data source.  Whether this data is publically/freely available going back many years I'm not sure.

Then, download from yahoo here all the price data available going back as far as you can for each security that at some point existed in the DAX.  Then connect the pieces.  Not sure there are any plug and play functions that will do this.

Comment: Historic components of the DAX index (day of index entry/exit ) can be found at `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAX#Former_DAX_components` then procede as suggested by @FXQuantTrader